# How do I access auth User's User.objects.create_user(...) in a south migration?

Tags: django, migration, django-authentication, django-south

Instead of using django's auth module I've used my own and already regret it a lot.

In an effort to rectify the situation, I'm trying to migrate the data from my User model to django.auth.models.User.

I've created a data migration as follows:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    """Migrate user information from mooi User model to auth User model."""

    OldUser = orm['mooi.User']
    User = orm['auth.User']
    Profile = orm['mooi.Profile']

    oldUsers = OldUser.objects.all()
    for oldUser in oldUsers:
        newUser = User.objects.create_user(username=oldUser.id, email=oldUser.email, password=oldUser.password)
        # ...more irrelevant code follows...
```

When I run the migration, I get this error (traceback):

```
#...irrelevant traceback precedes...
File "[projdir]/mooi/migrations/0005_from_mooi_users_create_auth_users_with_profiles.py", line 18, in forwards
    newUser = User.objects.create_user(username=oldUser.id, email=oldUser.email, password=oldUser.password)
  File "[virtual_env_dir]lib/python2.6/site-packages/south/orm.py", line 397, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.real, name)
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'
```

Upon further investigation, I discovered that the `Manager` that was being referred to was of time `south.orm.NoDryRunManager` which explains the error.

Now, the reason I even need `create_user` is to create a password hash that `django.contrib.auth` will understand.

Having said all that, how do I go about doing this? What's the most elegant solution given the hole I'm in?!

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

As suggested by [stevejalim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79225/stevejalim), I tried to use `User`'s `set_password(...)` as follows:

```
newUser.set_password(raw_password=oldUser.password)
newUser.save()
```

However that failed with this error:

```
File "[projdir]/mooi/migrations/0005_from_mooi_users_create_auth_users_with_profiles.py", line 21, in forwards
    newUser.set_password(raw_password=oldUser.password)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

I did find a hint in the [south documentation](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/ormfreezing.html#rationale-behind-the-serialisation) which states that:

> South doesn’t freeze every aspect of a
>   model; for example, **it doesn’t
>   preserve new managers, or custom model
>   methods**, as these would require
>   serialising the python code that runs
>   those method (and the code that
>   depends on, and so forth).
>
> If you want custom methods in your
>   migration, **you’ll have to copy the
>   code in, including any imports it
>   relies on to work**. Remember, however,
>   for every import that you add, you’re
>   promising to keep that import valid
>   for the life for the migration.

I guess the question remains, what's the best/safest way of doing this? Copy the `set_password(...)` method over? Create a function that hashes the password for me? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that South doesn't freeze methods at all, so calling any model methods is of no use.

The way I solved this was by coping and modifying the code in contrib.auth that generates passwords.

Here's how the final migration looks like:

```
# encoding: utf-8
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import DataMigration
from django.db import models

class Promise(object):
    """
    This is just a base class for the proxy class created in
    the closure of the lazy function. It can be used to recognize
    promises in code.
    """
    pass

def lazy(func, *resultclasses):
    """
    Turns any callable into a lazy evaluated callable. You need to give result
    classes or types -- at least one is needed so that the automatic forcing of
    the lazy evaluation code is triggered. Results are not memoized; the
    function is evaluated on every access.
    """

    class __proxy__(Promise):
        """
        Encapsulate a function call and act as a proxy for methods that are
        called on the result of that function. The function is not evaluated
        until one of the methods on the result is called.
        """
        __dispatch = None

        def __init__(self, args, kw):
            self.__func = func
            self.__args = args
            self.__kw = kw
            if self.__dispatch is None:
                self.__prepare_class__()

        def __reduce__(self):
            return (
                _lazy_proxy_unpickle,
                (self.__func, self.__args, self.__kw) + resultclasses
            )

        def __prepare_class__(cls):
            cls.__dispatch = {}
            for resultclass in resultclasses:
                cls.__dispatch[resultclass] = {}
                for (k, v) in resultclass.__dict__.items():
                    # All __promise__ return the same wrapper method, but they
                    # also do setup, inserting the method into the dispatch
                    # dict.
                    meth = cls.__promise__(resultclass, k, v)
                    if hasattr(cls, k):
                        continue
                    setattr(cls, k, meth)
            cls._delegate_str = str in resultclasses
            cls._delegate_unicode = unicode in resultclasses
            assert not (cls._delegate_str and cls._delegate_unicode), "Cannot call lazy() with both str and unicode return types."
            if cls._delegate_unicode:
                cls.__unicode__ = cls.__unicode_cast
            elif cls._delegate_str:
                cls.__str__ = cls.__str_cast
        __prepare_class__ = classmethod(__prepare_class__)

        def __promise__(cls, klass, funcname, func):
            # Builds a wrapper around some magic method and registers that magic
            # method for the given type and method name.
            def __wrapper__(self, *args, **kw):
                # Automatically triggers the evaluation of a lazy value and
                # applies the given magic method of the result type.
                res = self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
                for t in type(res).mro():
                    if t in self.__dispatch:
                        return self.__dispatch[t][funcname](res, *args, **kw)
                raise TypeError("Lazy object returned unexpected type.")

            if klass not in cls.__dispatch:
                cls.__dispatch[klass] = {}
            cls.__dispatch[klass][funcname] = func
            return __wrapper__
        __promise__ = classmethod(__promise__)

        def __unicode_cast(self):
            return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)

        def __str_cast(self):
            return str(self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))

        def __cmp__(self, rhs):
            if self._delegate_str:
                s = str(self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
            elif self._delegate_unicode:
                s = unicode(self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
            else:
                s = self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
            if isinstance(rhs, Promise):
                return -cmp(rhs, s)
            else:
                return cmp(s, rhs)

        def __mod__(self, rhs):
            if self._delegate_str:
                return str(self) % rhs
            elif self._delegate_unicode:
                return unicode(self) % rhs
            else:
                raise AssertionError('__mod__ not supported for non-string types')

        def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
            # Instances of this class are effectively immutable. It's just a
            # collection of functions. So we don't need to do anything
            # complicated for copying.
            memo[id(self)] = self
            return self

    def __wrapper__(*args, **kw):
        # Creates the proxy object, instead of the actual value.
        return __proxy__(args, kw)

    return wraps(func)(__wrapper__)


# code to encrypt passwords borrowed from django 1.2.1:
def smart_str(s, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'):
    """
    Returns a bytestring version of 's', encoded as specified in 'encoding'.

    If strings_only is True, don't convert (some) non-string-like objects.
    """
    if strings_only and isinstance(s, (types.NoneType, int)):
        return s
    if isinstance(s, Promise):
        return unicode(s).encode(encoding, errors)
    elif not isinstance(s, basestring):
        try:
            return str(s)
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            if isinstance(s, Exception):
                # An Exception subclass containing non-ASCII data that doesn't
                # know how to print itself properly. We shouldn't raise a
                # further exception.
                return ' '.join([smart_str(arg, encoding, strings_only,
                        errors) for arg in s])
            return unicode(s).encode(encoding, errors)
    elif isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode(encoding, errors)
    elif s and encoding != 'utf-8':
        return s.decode('utf-8', errors).encode(encoding, errors)
    else:
        return s

def get_hexdigest(algorithm, salt, raw_password):
    """
    Returns a string of the hexdigest of the given plaintext password and salt
    using the given algorithm ('md5', 'sha1' or 'crypt').
    """
    raw_password, salt = smart_str(raw_password), smart_str(salt)
    if algorithm == 'crypt':
        try:
            import crypt
        except ImportError:
            raise ValueError('"crypt" password algorithm not supported in this environment')
        return crypt.crypt(raw_password, salt)
    # The rest of the supported algorithms are supported by hashlib, but
    # hashlib is only available in Python 2.5.
    try:
        import hashlib
    except ImportError:
        if algorithm == 'md5':
            import md5
            return md5.new(salt + raw_password).hexdigest()
        elif algorithm == 'sha1':
            import sha
            return sha.new(salt + raw_password).hexdigest()
    else:
        if algorithm == 'md5':
            return hashlib.md5(salt + raw_password).hexdigest()
        elif algorithm == 'sha1':
            return hashlib.sha1(salt + raw_password).hexdigest()
    raise ValueError("Got unknown password algorithm type in password.")

def get_encrypted_password(raw_password):
    import random
    algo = 'sha1'
    salt = get_hexdigest(algo, str(random.random()), str(random.random()))[:5]
    hsh = get_hexdigest(algo, salt, raw_password)
    return '%s$%s$%s' % (algo, salt, hsh)


class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        """Migrate user information from mooi User model to auth User model."""

        OldUser = orm['mooi.User']
        User = orm['auth.User']
        Profile = orm['mooi.Profile']

        oldUsers = OldUser.objects.all()
        for oldUser in oldUsers:
            newUser = User(username=oldUser.id, email=oldUser.email)
            newUser.first_name = oldUser.name
            newUser.save()
            newUser.password = get_encrypted_password(oldUser.password)
            newUser.save()
            newUserProfile = Profile(user=newUser)
            newUserProfile.phone = oldUser.phone
            newUserProfile.credits = oldUser.credits
            newUserProfile.transaction_status = oldUser.transaction_status
            newUserProfile.location = oldUser.location
            newUserProfile.save()
            assert oldUser.id == newUser.username, \
                "Old user: %s, is not equal to: %s" % (oldUser.id, newUser.username)
            assert oldUser.name == newUser.first_name, \
                "Names don't match, old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.name, newUser.first_name)
            assert oldUser.email == newUser.email, \
                "Emails don't match, old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.email, newUser.email)
            assert oldUser.phone == newUserProfile.phone, \
                "Phones don't match, old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.phone, newUserProfile.phone)
            assert oldUser.credits == newUserProfile.credits, \
                "Credits don't match, old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.credits, newUserProfile.credits)
            assert oldUser.transaction_status == newUserProfile.transaction_status, \
                "Trans. status don't match, old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.transaction_status, newUserProfile.transaction_status)
            assert oldUser.location == newUserProfile.location, \
                "Locations don't match: old: %s, new: %s" % (oldUser.location == newUserProfile.location)
```

Answer (score 5):

Why you don't just import what you need?.
I had the same problem and what I did was:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class Migration(DataMigration):
    ...

    def forwards(self, orm):
        user = orm['auth.User'].objects....
        user.password = make_password('123')
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole point behind using the frozen ORM in migrations is to ensure that new changes don't interfere with old implementations.  The auth app is part of `django.contrib`, and I doubt the functionality you're looking for has changed much in the past few releases, or is planned to change anytime soon.  Aside from that, you're not going to be modifying the (auth) app or its models (right?  right??).  So it's pretty safe to say you don't *need* to use South's frozen version of `auth.User`; just import it normally and use it that way.

Comment: Model methods don't import, which causes the problem, not the model itself.

Comment: As I understand it, the problem is that South doesn't freeze `auth.User`'s utility methods, which are what you're after, in its frozen orm.  Does `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and then using that `User` not solve the problem?  Does it cause issues elsewhere?

Comment: You cannot do that type of importing in South. I posted the complete migration file below (except for the model description part).

Comment: Eternicode's solution worked for me using Django 1.5.1 and South 0.7.6. I don't know if it was previously impossible to import models directly in South, but it works now and is much simpler than Pilgrim's workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the `User` manually, then set the password after it has been `save()`d with `newUser.set_password()`? Yes, you'll need to hit the DB twice, but that's no great shakes.

Comment: Not a bad idea, except, I still get an error: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'set_password'.

Comment: In that case, lift the code from django.contrib.auth.models.User for set_password() [and get_hexdigest()] - it's about 30 lines all-in